# Installing .net MVC 3 on Windows XP SP3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 on my pc (WinXP SP3). I am trying to install .net MVC 3.

After couple of minutes Installer says it is installed.
[image]

but it doesn't appear on the installed project templates. 
[image]
How can I resolve this issue. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the **DotNet Framework to 4.0** and see and you will see the MVC3 Project there.

[image]

Comment: @KanishkaDilshan :Glad it helped you.